# mouse position count

Tags: jquery, count, position, mouse, latitude-longitude

Hi I'm using Jquery's mouse position to find the position of the page.

I would like it to have it behave more like latitude and longitude coordinates.

```
    $().mousemove(function(e){
        $('#detect').html( e.pageX + '° N, '+ e.pageY + '° E' );

    });
```

I realise this is not true latitude and longitude coordinates. The box would be the webpage, and 0 is absolute middle of the webpage. Moving the mouse into the N/E area would produce this result.

[image: NSEW]

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I didn't see your edit, I made you a code if it still interest you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript:

```
var screenX = $(document).width() / 2;
var screenY = $(document).height() / 2;

$(document).mousemove(function(e){

    var apX = screenX - e.pageX;
    var apY = screenY - e.pageY;

    var latT = (apY>=0) ? 'N' : 'S';
    var lonT = (apX>=0) ? 'W' : 'E';

    apX = Math.round(Math.abs(apX));
    apY = Math.round(Math.abs(apY));

    $('#detect').html( apX  + 'px '+ latT +', '+ apY + 'px '+ lonT  );

});
```

You can find a test on http://jsfiddle.net/nvwzH/

Comment: I think the coordinates are wrong but I think that was my initial mistake. http://jsfiddle.net/nvwzH/2/ Thanks for your help.